# Find the average of $P$ defined on the Fat Cantor set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, average, cantor-set

Suppose we have $P:A\to[0,1]$, where $A$ is the fat cantor set denoted as $C$.

We produce $C$ by removing $1/4$ of $[0,1]$ around mid-point $1/2$

$$C_{1}=[0,3/8]\cup [5/8,1]$$

$$C_{1,1}=[0,3/8] \ \ \ \ \ \ C_{1,2}=[5/8,1]$$

We repeat, removing $1/16$ of $[0,1]$ around each midpoint of remaining intervals $C_{1,1}$ and $C_{1,2}$.

$$C_{2}=[0,5/32]\cup[7/32,12/32]\cup[5/8,25/32]\cup[27/32,1]$$

$$C_{2,1}=[0,5/32] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C_{2,2}=[7/32,12/32] \ \ \ \ C_{2,3}=[5/8,25/32] \ \ \ C_{2,4}=[27/32,1]$$

Repeat the process until $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}C_{n}=C$, where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1/4^n$ of $[0,1]$ around each midpoint of remaining intervals are removed.

I want to find the average, in terms of integration, such that it is equivelant to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n}} P(t_{n,i})(1/2^n)$$

Where $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{2^{n}}C_{n,i}=C_n$ and $t_{n,i}\in C_{n,i}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is continuous, the average should be $\dfrac{1}{m(C)} \int_C P(x)\; dx$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

EDIT:
It looks to me like if $C(i)$ is the $i$'th iteration starting at $C(0)=[0,1]$, $a_i = \int_{C(i)} x^2\; dx$ has
generating function
$$ g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i = {\frac {35\,{x}^{3}-1066\,{x}^{2}+7456\,x-8192}{ 3 \left( x-1
 \right)  \left( x-2 \right)  \left( x-16 \right)  \left( x-8 \right) 
 \left( x-32 \right) }}$$
and $\lim_{i \to \infty} a_i$ is $-$ the residue of this at $x=1$, namely $19/105$.  Dividing by the measure of $C$, namely $1/2$, I get the average for $P(x)=x^2$ to be $38/105$.

Comment: For example, if $P=x^2$ what would the average be? According to [my sum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218624/34171) the average should be $4/11$.

Comment: Apologies according to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218624/34171), it should be $4/11$. I had to detract from accepting your answer. Are you sure you didn't make a mistake?

Comment: I'm quite confident that it is less than $4/11$.  Even $\int_{C(8)} x^2 \; dx = \frac{4793674346291}{26388279066624} < 2/11$, so $\int_{C} x^2 \; dx < 2/11$.  And since $m(C) = 1/2$, that means the average $< 4/11$.

Comment: Where can I read about this average?